# Re-open stdout in binary mode?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to run a python script on a Windows host. The data generated by the script should be piped to another process. This process expects Unix style line endings. How can I control the output endings of my script?

Script excerpt:

```
print "blob"
print "mark: %d" & mark
print "data %d" % os.path.getsize(localPath)
    with open(localPath, "rb") as f:
        print f.read()
```

This should generate:

```
"blob\nmark: 0\n"
```

The script generates text *and* binary output. So it's not an option to convert the result with a dos2unix program later.

Can I re-open stdout in binary mode to avoid the \n -> \r\n conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output can be controlled by passing a python command line argument: -u. This causes unbuffered output and *skips the LF -> CRLF conversion*.

It's also possible to specify this in the bang line:

```
#!/C/Python27/python -u
```